# mostrar "table" con la información del cliente logueado

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo una tabla donde traigo de base de datos la información de las órdenes.
en ella me muestra todas las órdenes pertenecientes a todos los usuarios y por ende a todos los cliente. con hago para que solo me muestra en la tabla las órdenes correspondientes al cliente del usuario logueado actualmente.

es decir si estoy logueado con mi usuario USER1 que pertenece al cliente GOOGLE debe mostrar solo las ordenes que le pertenecen a dicho cliente.

mi tabla:

```
<table class="table" id="orden-tabla">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Empresa</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($ordenes as $orden)
        <tr>
           <td>{!! $orden->id !!}</td>
           <td>{!! $orden->paciente_Orden->nombre !!}</td>
           <td>{!! $orden->orden_sucursal->nombre !!}</td>
           <td>
                {!! Form::open(['route' => ['ordenes.destroy', $orden->id], 'method' => 'delete','style'=>'margin-left: 14%;']) !!}
                <div class='btn-group'>                       
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

index

```
@push('script')
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#orden-tabla').DataTable({
      "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sRowSelect": "multi"
        },
        "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
    });
  });
</script>
@endpush()
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona o cuál es el error? No queda claro.

Comment: Pues a como lo estas planteando eso esta al momento de realizar tu consulta a la base de datos, tiene que decirle que solo te traiga las ordenes que tengan el id del usuario.

Comment: deberias modificar tu consulta donde traes las ordenes.. $ordenes....y consultar por el id del cliente o usuario

Comment: @Shaz El problema es que me trae todos los registros de mi tabla ordenes y lo que necesito es que me traiga los registros correspondientes al cliente del usuario logueado actualmente.

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado no logro saber de qué manera interpretarlo ya que no es al usuario sino al cliente de ese usuario.

Comment: Muéstranos el código del backend (especialmente donde realizas la consulta) para poder colaborar.

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar solo las ordenes que pertenecen a un usuario en especifico se debe realizar un filtrado de la información desde el momento que se realiza la consulta. Por ejemplo:

SELECT * FROM ordenes WHERE usuario = 10;

Es mala práctica traer todos los registros existentes en la tabla y posteriormente hacer un filtrado para solo mostrar aquellos que sean de un usuario en especifico puesto que, con una mínima cantidad de registros puede que no exista mayor problema pero ¿qué pasaría si hay 10,000 registros?.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, ya me funciona y lo realice de la siguiente manera:

en mi controlador.

```
    public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $this->ordenRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
            $ordenes = $this->ordenRepository->all();
            $ordenCliente = Orden::where('cliente_id', Auth::user()->cliente_id)->get(); 
            ...
            return view('ordenes.index', compact('ordenCliente','ordenes'));
        }
```

y en mi tabla

```
   @foreach($ordenCliente as $orden)

        <tr>
            <td>{!! $orden->id !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $orden->paciente_Orden->nombre !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $orden->observacion !!}</td>
          ...
```